# Racket call function on each element of list

Tags: list, racket

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of divisors, a list of numbers to test and applies drop-divisible for each element of the list of divisors. I am supposed to use filter, map or foldl and no recursion

I wrote the drop-divisible function:

```
(define (drop-divisible l n)
 (cond
  [(empty? l) empty]
  [(empty? (rest l)) l]
   (let ([i (first l)])
    (if (zero? (modulo i n))
    (drop-divisible (rest l) n)
    (cons i (drop-divisible(rest l)n))))]))
```

That seems to work, but I'm confused on how I can call drop-divisible for each element in the list when it only wants one list and an integer as a parameter?

Hopefully, that makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want "all the elements of this list except the ones that meet such-and-such criterion", the [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) function provides an easy way to do that:

```
(define (drop-divisible l n)
  (filter (λ (i) (not (zero? (modulo i n))))
          l))

> (drop-divisible '(4 6 9 8 12 14) 3)
'(4 8 14)
```

`filter` constructs a new list, containing only the items of the original list that meet your criterion. The first argument to `filter` is a function that takes a single element of the list and returns `#f` if the element should be skipped when creating the new list, and returns any other value to include the element in the new list. The second argument to `filter` is the list to filter.

In other words, `filter` does exactly what your code does, but it's generalized to apply any filtering criterion.